# Invalid token 'token' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create the following Class:

```
public decimal base { get; set; }
```

and I get the error mentioned. Any solution please?
Thank you.

I'm trying to create the following Class and I get the error mentioned. Any solution please? Thank you

Comment: 'base' is a keyword, therefore it can not be used as a property name. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/base

Comment: It's impossible?

Comment: You could by prefixing the name with `@`, but I'd recommend sticking with [.NET Naming Convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/general-naming-conventions)

Answer (score 3):

If you want the value to map to it, you need to add the 'JsonProperty' attribute indicating the name of the property.

```cs
[JsonProperty("base")]
public decimal Base { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

`base` is a special C# keyword.

Anyways, public properties should begin with uppercase letter:

```
public decimal Base { get; set; }
```

Comment: The problem is that the json that another application receives is in lower case and they cannot change it

Comment: Just use camel case naming encoding during serialization